# Firebase AppCheck PERMISSION_DENIED after changing iOS app's name

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-app-check

I have an app which connects to Firebase and uses Firestore. I implemented AppAttest, added all the `AppCheckFactory`s for `DEBUG` and production and everything worked just fine.

After that I needed to change the name of the app so that's what I did – changed the name everywhere. My App and Target name is different now, and AppCheck stopped working. For the context: bundle id remained the same. I changed project name in Firebase but project id remained the same. The App Check now returns this on app launch:

```
"error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "App attestation failed.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

What do I miss? Or maybe the better question would be: what does App Attest depend on to persist its integrity?

Comment: @tensai, nope, unfortunately not

Comment: So what work arounds did you employ?

Comment: Ok. I have gotten a lot further now. I used the following before i initializedApp "self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;"

Comment: Note this is just for local development. I will have to see what things look like after I deploy this code. Check out this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/debug-provider#web-modular-api

Comment: @tensai I talked to Firebase support and they suggest to create a new project on Firebase and link everything anew